# Cannot connect to arvixe database in my SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, plesk

I have to access my arvixe.com database in my `SQL Server Management Studio 2014`. Can Anybody guide me? Screenshot attached. What was the problem with it

[image]

Comment: Your URL is wrong. Are your sure 8443 as port, normally is 1433 for Sql Server. Remove https also

Comment: @YogeshSharma Still same issue

Comment: @JoeTaras I have to access arvixe database and i am sure arvixe has 8443 port

Comment: mare sure u have Internet connection or SQL Service is runing

Comment: 8443 port is for your application server. But for your database connection I suppose you must to change your port.

Comment: Please check if server is online

Comment: The server is managed by you or you use a service provider for server?

Comment: Please contact your hosting provider and ask the details that you need to use.

Comment: @MarkSpencer Thanx Issue resolved and an answer was provided for in future if anyone found this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server name: ws4.win.arvixe.com
Login: Your Database Username
Password: your password

[This article helps me alot](http://www.codengames.com/Articles/Details/31)

Answer (score 0):

I try to telnet your server `ws4.win.arvixme.com` on `1433` port and it replies me.

So you must to change your server connection as follow:

```
Server name: ws4.win.arvixe.com:1433
Login: anstylec_dealbargains
Password: your password
```

When you access to your application server by browser you'll write:

```
https://ws4.win.arvixe.com:8443
```

But the port of your database is different

**Pay attention**

The upper solution is if the server has managed by service provider.

If the database server has managed by you, please follow these steps:

```
Go to `Sql Server Setting`
And arrive until this leaf of your tree (I can post the italian version)
```

[image: Selected leaf]

So check if TCP/IP is enabled.

If yes click on it and check the port

Comment: @Azazulhaq: I don't understand if the server is managed by you or third part

Comment: I see my port by
Sql Server Configuration Manager>SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration>Client Protocols>TCP/IP>Properties>Default Port = 1433

Comment: Ok, so have you tried to change the server name in your connection? If you want to create a new user (named joetaras password joetaras) on your db server and I try to access.

Comment: thanks, @Joe Taras I conclude my error. When I enabled my TCP/IP status enabled from SQL Network Configuration. My SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) instance is not able to start after restart

Comment: @Azazulhaq:Ok, have a nice day